# Use squeeze Theorem to evaluate the limit

Tags: limits

Use squeeze Theorem to evaluate the limit : $ \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (3,4)} (x^2-9)\cos ( \frac{1}{(x-3)^2+(y-4)^2}) $

**Answer:**

Let $ \ f(x,y)=(x^2-9)\cos ( \frac{1}{(x-3)^2+(y-4)^2}) $ . We know that

$ -1 \leq \cos ( \frac{1}{(x-3)^2+(y-4)^2}) \leq 1 \ \ \forall \ x,y $

or,$ -(x^2-9) \leq (x^2-9) \leq \cos ( \frac{1}{(x-3)^2+(y-4)^2}) \leq x^2-9 $

or, $ \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (3,4)} -(x^2-9) \leq \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (3,4)} (x^2-9)  \cos ( \frac{1}{(x-3)^2+(y-4)^2}) \leq \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (3,4)} (x^2-9) $

or, $ 0 \leq \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (3,4)} (x^2-9)  \cos ( \frac{1}{(x-3)^2+(y-4)^2}) \leq 0 $ .

Hence , $ \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (3,4)} (x^2-9)  \cos ( \frac{1}{(x-3)^2+(y-4)^2}) =0 $

**Am I right ? Any help ?**

Comment: More succinctly, $$\left|\cos\left(\frac{1}{(x-3)^2+(y-4)^2}\right)\right|\le 1$$Hence, $$0\le \left|(x^2-9)\cos\left(\frac{1}{(x-3)^2+(y-4)^2}\right)\right|\le |x^2-9|$$

Comment: Your general approach is entirely correct, but You'll need to be careful about the claim $9-x^2\le f(x, y)\le x^2 - 9$ as this inequality is only true for $x<3$. You'll probably want to use $|f(x, y)|\le |x^2 - 9|$ instead.

Comment: The answer is $ 0$ . Right ?